# Comparing objects of DateTime in php is not working

Tags: php, api, datetime, time, web-development-server

I am making an API in which I need to check the token validity for a particular user and for that I am using DateTime function of php. I am saving a token and current time on login and I want token to be valid for 10 minutes, so when a user makes a request within first 10 minutes of its login I want to update the time validity of token.

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$curTime = $currentTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time10MinutesAgo = new DateTime("10 minutes ago");
$time10Minutes = $time10MinutesAgo->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$token_time = $query1_r['token_time']; // value is stored in the db(mysql)
if (($curTime > $token_time) && ($token_time >= $time10Minutes)){}
```

first I was unable to pass the second condition but now even my page is not working.

Comment: `$curTime` and `$token_time` and `$time10Minutes` are strings, and __not__ `DateTime` objects.

Comment: how can I make it work ?

Comment: @u_mulder why comparing $time10MInuteAgo and $token_time is creating a problem ?

Comment: What problem it creates?

Comment: @u_mulder ($curTime > $token_time) this condition is working fine and ($token_time >= $time10Minutes) this condition is not working.

Comment: $currentTime = new DateTime();
        $currentTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $time10MinutesAgo = new DateTime("10 minutes ago");
        echo $time10MinutesAgo->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        echo $token_time =$query1_r['token_time'];
        if($token_time > $time10MinutesAgo) {echo "1";}

Comment: I ask you once again __do you understand that your variables are strings__, not datetime objects?

Comment: If you want to compare `DateTime` then __forget about strings__.

Comment: on wrtitephponline it is also working fine

Comment: @u_mulder I got that point but why my two strings are not comparable

Comment: Print them out and see.

Comment: What is in `$query1_r['token_time']`? Convert that also to DateTime object: `$token_time = new DateTime($query1_r['token_time']);` and code will start to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have DateTime object, don't convert them to strings, just compare objects between each other, like this:

```php
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$time10MinutesAgo = new DateTime("10 minutes ago");
$tokenTime = new DateTime($query1_r['token_time']);

if ($time10MinutesAgo <= $tokenTime && $tokenTime <= $currentTime) {
    echo "Token time is between now and now-10 minutes.";
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/975623)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Use epoch time values for time comparisons it's much easier to compare numbers instead of dates.

```
$currentTime = time();
$time10MinutesAgo = strtotime('-10 minutes');
$token_time = strtotime($query1_r['token_time']); // value is stored in the db(mysql)
if(($currentTime >$token_time) && ($token_time >= $time10MinutesAgo )){}
```

Comment: Actually I was Date function before and was converting them to timestamp but that process was taking more time, plus my main concern is why comparing $time10MInuteAgo and $token_time is creating a problem ?

Comment: @PrakharSharma I wouldn't ever use string comparisons for time, much easier with integer comparisons with epoch formatting.

Comment: @PrakharSharma you're welcome, please accept my answer :)